# BlackList Json discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, discord, discord.py

i want to make a blacklist system for my discord.py bot in async... i want to use a json rather then a database im just really confused atm

````py
@client.command()
async def blacklist(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    with open('blacklist.json', 'r')as f:
        users = json.load(f)
        if user.id in users:
            await client.say("already blacklisted")
        else:
            with open('blacklist.json', 'w')as f:
                json.dump(users, f)
                if not user.id in users:
                    users[user.id] = {}
                await client.say(f"done!! {member.name} has been blacklisted")```
````

Comment: What about this code isn't working the way you expect?  Are you seeing an error message?

Answer (score 1):

If `blacklist.json` is a list, you can do:

```py
@client.command()
async def blacklist(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
        return
    with open('blacklist.json', 'r+') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
        if member.id in users:
            await client.say("already blacklisted")
            return
        users.append(member.id)
        f.seek(0)
        json.dump(users, f)
        f.truncate()
        await client.say(f"done!! {member.mention} has been blacklisted")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
@client.command()
async def blacklist(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    with open('blacklist.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    if user.id in users:
        await client.say("already blacklisted")
    else:
        with open('blacklist.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
        if not user.id in users:
            users[user.id] = {}
            await client.say(f"done!! {member.name} has been blacklisted")
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to include explanation for future readers.